# High Availablity for ASP.Net Application

Tags: iis, azure, cloud, cloud-hosting, high-availability

We have a situation where I need a High Availablity solution for one of our application made using ASP.Net 3.5.

The client is expecting about 50k people accessing the application at a given time and we are then roughly expecting about 5% simultanions hits to the application.

A typical transaction include an filled up form and documents of about 20mb attached.

I would like to know the following:

1. Where can I get infomation regrding throughput/performance of IIS supporting the above usage requirements?
2. My client has got their own Datacenter and they would like to keep an instance running on their infrastructure.

Bearing this requirement in mind, is it possible for me to have other instances running on cloud (Windows Azure preferably) and load balance all these instances including the one in client's datacenter? If so how can I achieve this?

Anyother suggestions for the given scenario is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET runs some of the biggest sites on the web..DELL, MySpace, Microsoft etc.

When you say ASP.NET..it can mean a lot of things.  I assume you are talking about web forms, but you could have a lot of Ajax talking to web services etc.

You can scale ASP.NET to millions of users, here is an example for ASP.NET 3.5:
http://www.slideshare.net/oazabir/scaling-aspnet-websites-to-millions-of-users#btnNext

It is hard to answer your question not knowing your architecture design.  Knee jerk answer is yes it can scale to your user numbers.  I have scaled ASP.NET to that degree.

---

Azure can absolutely be used to scale the website further.  In fact, many large sites have their own hosting and then scale to the cloud when necessary (i.e. Zynga uses Amazon) or Apple scales iCloud to two clouds using BOTH Microsoft and Amazon.  Azure includes a stateless load balancer, so sticky sessions and custom load balancing on session based web forms is possible..but you would need to either:
1) write a small software load balanced server on premises to route the requests appropriately OR 
2) store your session state in a "common area" like Azure Caching, Azure Table Storage, SQL Azure etc (basically not InProc session state).  Azure AppFabric caching includes modules that you can replace InProc caching with.

You could also write a "dumb" load balancer, where some clients are always in the cloud and some are always hosted.  That would be a lot easier.